# tf.train.batch in distributed training returns OutOfRangeError

Tags: tensorflow, pyspark

I am using distributed tensorflow to read data files from HDFS paths to do training.

Each worker will run `tf.train.batch` to retrieve the data batches from the same set of files. I try to re-run the program many times. For every run, an inconsistent subset of workers will return `OutOfRangeError` in the beginning of training when there are files to read. It will throw:

`FIFOQueue '_0_batch_csv/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2048, current size 0)`

Is that the thread to enqueue the queue with things from HDFS paths too slow?

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that kind of issues so I did some check. But as I mentioned, the logic of each worker is the same and they are reading same set of files. But only some of them will throw this error. Therefore, I believe the problem is not about path/filenames.

Comment: A side note is that some queue got enqueued twice with the same data which is not intentional.